Calling proper program for compression, speed and percentage count using command line in Linux
I am working on a computer that is constantly being pegged out. I am needing to compress several very large (close to a TB) files. I need to do this using the Linux command line.
The issue is I need relatively good compression but I need to control the compression speed so my system doesn't freeze up since I also have a couple of large transfers in the TB range going on between HHD's. I also need it to display the % done.
Considered this compress -v path/to/file , since most all of what is in this dir is in text form I would like to ask if I need to call on a certain program for the compression strengths and with that certain program in mind consider the best command line argument to pair it with so I get the percentage count and a proper speed throttling.
This has always been a weakness in my skill-set.

"a computer that is constantly being pegged out" - although a native English speaker, I'm not familiar with "pegged out". What do you mean?

Yes, a more clear description of just how high your system's resource usage is, loads brought by the tasks you mention, further details regarding those tasks, and perhaps some basic details of your computer's specifications will all help make this question more clear. Please note that while the first goal of your question is to get good answers, the second, and just as important, goal is to be of benefit to others who may have the same/similar issues in the future. This is a big part of why we require a clear description of the problem.

As the first recommendation, the compress command uses an old and fairly inefficient LZW algorithm – claimed to be slower and give lower compression ratios than most newer alternatives. Consider replacing it with at least gzip or possibly the more modern zstd.
Then start it with nice to set a lower CPU priority (and from it, a lower I/O priority). This doesn't throttle it, only deprioritizes it, so the program can still use all CPU resources if nothing else needs them at the moment.
nice -n 19 compress foo.txt

You can also add ionice in a similar way, but the default Linux I/O scheduler already infers I/O priority from niceness value, so I'm not sure if you can go much lower (except for ionice -c idle, which on a highly-loaded system will just mean that your process won't get any time).
To get a progress report, you can use pv in two ways:

Directly in the pipeline:
pv foo.txt | compress > foo.txt.Z
pv foo.txt | gzip > foo.txt.gz

(Limits should be applied to both, i.e. nice pv | nice gzip.)

Inspect an already running process:
pv -d <pid_of_gzip>



In the first case, pv can also be used to throttle the input to compress/gzip:
nice pv --rate-limit 10M foo.txt | nice compress > foo.txt.gz

With systemd, you can also put the process in a dedicated cgroup with its own CPU limits, as documented in man systemd.resource-control:
systemd-run --user --pty -d -G -p Nice=19 -p CPUWeight=10 compress foo.txt

Don't try pv | systemd-run gzip > foo, though; that won't work – do that manually via systemd-run --user --shell [-p this -p that] instead (…or at least remove the --pty before trying, to avoid corruption).

Doing it on the Linux CLI is a great advantage! The answer by @grawity_u1686 gives you very good advice to accomplish your task efficiently.

@grawity_u1686 that is a ton to take in. Yes I think your answer is dead on but I will be re-reading it to take it all in. I thank you very much for your assistance!

Sorry I got called away for a bit. A quick review of the input here is great. I considered some of the responses here before I posted. I was not sure how I should go about some though. I am sure the answer is located in your input. As soon as I get back in the grove here I will try a couple of these.
